# Deal with stripped washing machine inlet

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

I have a washing machine with a stripped water inlet. Is there an easy solution to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Despite being a different brand, the outgoing washer used the same inlet valve assembly. I was able to swap the parts, and the stripped inlet is going to the metal recycling center with the old washer.

[image]

Comment: Well done. The best recycling is immediate reuse...